# Animating the background color of an HTML table's cell (or the whole row) on an event

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

I have a table with a menu (food items) with several rows and columns.
The 2nd column contains a link to the food item. When the user clicks it,
the item is added to a shopping cart.

I'd like to give the user some visual feedback that the click and adding
actually worked. I already have a click handler for the link that adds the
item clicked on to the cart. A simple `alert('Item successfully added');`
works but is not really pretty.

I'd like the table cell (or the whole row) to "flash" once. By "flashing"
I mean "change its background color smoothly from current (light gray) to
e.g. yellow and then back to normal". This should happen only once.

I'm using jQuery 2.x and Bootstrap 3.x.

My (simplified) code so far looks like this:

```js
  $('a[href="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    // code to add the item to shopping cart (AJAX), omitted here
    // Upon successful return of the AJAX data:
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a href="#">Hamburger</a>
    </td>
    <td>2.65</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><a href="#">Cheeseburger</a>
    </td>
    <td>3.25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I make the row flash instead of simply changing its background color?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's often best to use CSS classes rather than directly manipulating styles:

```js
$('a[href="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    // code to add the item to shopping cart (AJAX), omitted here
    // Upon successful return of the AJAX data:
    var myRow = $(this).closest('tr');

    myRow.addClass('stylish');

    setTimeout(function() {
        myRow.removeClass('stylish');
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
tr {
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

.stylish {
    background-color: orange;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><a href="#">Hamburger</a>
        </td>
        <td>2.65</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><a href="#">Cheeseburger</a>
        </td>
        <td>3.25</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8zqznzsg)**

Comment: Wow! I was already struggling with the `@keyframes` stuff and didn't get it right. Wasn't aware of `delay()` and `queue()`. Pretty cool. (I already have a custom.css, just omitted it here for simplification.)