# How to change row color of HTML table using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code :

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    var rows = "<tr id='tblrow' align='center'>" +
               "<td id='DriveThruindicator'>" + "<img id='ImgDriveThru' src='images/car_image.JPG'>" + "</img>" + "</td>" +
               "<td id='Name'>" + item.user.firstName + " " + item.user.lastName.charAt(0) + "." + "</td>" +
               "<td id='PickupMethod'>" + PickupMethodEnum[item.pickupType] + "</td>" +
               "<td id='Total'>" + item.total + "</td>" +
               "<td id='ScheduledTime'>" + Date(item.pickupTimeUtc, "dd-MM-yyyy") + "</td>" +
               "<td style='background-color: darkorange; color: white'>" + "***" + "</td>" +
               "</tr>";
               //   $('#DriveThruindicator').append('<img src="images/car_image.JPG" >');
               $('#tblOrders').append(rows);
```

I want to change the row color based on `PickupMethodEnum[item.pickupType]`: If `pickuptype="DriveThru"` then  change the color to gray and remove the row after 2 minutes.

Also I want to show scheduledTime in a custom format:

- If `scheduledTime` is current date then display as `12:15 pm`.
- If `scheduledTime` is tomorrow date the display as `8/10 - 7:00am`.

Comment: Improved formatting.

Comment: Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140684/animating-the-background-color-of-an-html-tables-cell-or-the-whole-row-on-an

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get, what you want to do.
You can change the color using jQuery's `.css()` like that: `$("selector here").css("color", "grey")`.
And you can use native js to delay something like that: `setTimeout(function(){Code}, delayInMs)`.
Hope this helps.